# Is it possible that an EC2 instance will change its private IP at any given time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that hosts a Ruby on Rails App which in turn connects to a RDS instance. Everything is working fine for several months until the rails app encountered an issue wherein the connection to the RDS database times out.

It turns out that when I checked the EC2 instance in the dashboard, the private IP address of the EC2 instance is not part of the inbound restriction of the security group that I'm using. I'm sure that I didn't remove the security group entry of this instance. However, I didn't record the private IP address of this instance until the issue happened.

So my question is, is it possible that an EC2 instance will change its private IP at any given time? If yes, is there a way to always allow this instance to access my RDS instance? I already tried using the public IP instead for the security group but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. An EC2 instance **will always retain the same Private IP address**. (The *Public IP address* can change after a stop/start, but the *Private IP address* will never change.)

Regardless, rather than putting an IP address in a security group, you should **reference another security group**.

For example:

- Create an **App Security Group**:

  - Associate it with the EC2 instance
  - Open ports required by your application (eg HTTP port 80)
- Create a **Database Security Group**:

  - Associate it with the RDS database
  - Open the database port, with **Source = App Security Group**

This means that any EC2 instance that is associated with the App Security Group will be permitted to communicate with the database -- this will work for multiple instances and there is no need to specify any specific IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. Unfortunately, my ec2 instance is not in VPC so turns out, I can't change the security group.

Answer (score 1):

No. The **private IP is associated with the EC2 instance for life of the instance**. Until you terminate the instance, the private IP remains with the IP.
It will never change.

Someone may have modified the security group to allow a different set of IPs. If you know how to check CloudTrail, you can find out the reason for this new behavior.